# Error loading .a files in questasim

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I have a problem when i try to load the `.a` files i got provided in a Questasim project.
I tried to do it when invoking `vlog` but I don't see any intuitive option when to do so.

I found that I could use `-sv_lib` for .so files in `vsim` but I don't know when I
should load `.a` should this be with the `-ccflags` when invoking `vlog`?

Should the .so and .a file be loaded in `vopt` or `vsim`? Tried to add it to `-ccflags -l foo.a` but didn't seem like it did much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a shared object from your .a file first. Look at the section "*Compiling and Linking C Applications for Interfaces*" in the QuestaSim User Manual.